# Mock web service using mocking framework without using junit

Tags: java, web-services, mocking, mockito

This is my web service

```
@Path("/base")
public class ServiceMappingBusinessLogic1 {
    @Mock Buiness1Service mockbusinesss1service;

    @GET
    public Response getService( String id) {

          when(mockbusinessservice.getService("id")).thenReturn("mockservice");


        String service =  mockbusinessservice.getService();
        return Response.status(200).entity(service).build();

    }
    This is serviceInterface



public interface Buiness1Service {
        String getService(String id);
    }
```

Buiness1Service is not implemented yet so,i am trying to use mock service

I am using SOAP UI to Test service .I am using jersey.

I am trying to use Mockito as mock service provider.But,from the testing i have confirmed that mockito does not mock alone it need unit testing framework like junit to work together.
I am unable  mock service only using mockito.

**So,my question is how to mock service without including  junit in  web service layer .In my case i need to mock Buiness1Service  service ,but i am unable do that.Any good idea ?Please help**

Answer (score 1):

why cant you provide Buiness1Service class like

```
public class Buiness1ServiceImpl implements Buiness1Service{
    public String getService(String id){
        return "mockservice";
    }
}
```

?